# Remove the mutation (or corruption) from a base64 string

Tags: javascript, base64

I upload a file using the file from the browser using the file type input. I have a system,  where I receive that file on the client side read the binary of it and then convert it to base64 `(using btoa)`, do some more stuff as part of my system and then the system uploads it to the remote Apache server as a `Multipart` request.

When I download the file, I do the reverse, parse the response, get the raw string, convert it to `base64`, send that string to client side and convert that base64 string into binary again `(using atob)` and save the file using `octet-stream` type using `Blob` constructor and the `createObjectURL` method. The file is saved on the disk, so no problem here. When I open the file it's content is unreadable.

I did some research and compared my `base64` during upload with the `base64` during the download part and I see that the `base64` string gets corrupted in the download process.
So, for example, I am just making up the strings,  but the intent is to show what is happening

Upload base64:
UIABvcf`ce+t`re2df

Download corrupted base64:
UIABvcf`Duuuvvv55rr`re2df

You would see as shown above `ce+t` is changed to `Duuuvvv55rr`.
And therefore, my question - How to remove the mutation (or corruption) from a base64 string?
I tried a lot of search on stackoverflow and other online platform with direct or indirect references but somewhere it is not working.

Comment: that should never happen  - perhaps there's a character encoding issue happening - does the server "decode" the base64?

Comment: there's no magical way to 'remove' this mutation, you need to prevent it happening. there's something in your process introducing the change, you need to narrow down what it is more precisely. check the representation at each point in the process and see where the mutation is happening, then dig into the code between that step and the previous one to find the fault.

Comment: @JaromandaX,  if a do a `Download and save` using Postman,  I get the right file.

Comment: Postman isn't a browser, so ...